# Mediaelementjs in Wordpress not working

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js

alright, I've busted my brain trying to figure this out.
I'm trying to use the mediaelementjs audio player in my Wordpress site and have read a bunch of tutorials saying that mediaelementjs is now part of the Wordpress Core and that a simple [audio] reference will make the player live.

However, every time I try it I just get a blank Soundcloud box that says "url is not a valid soundcloud address".

I've tried the enque method in functions.php for custom js but all it does is break the js that's used for mobile devices.

Is this an issue with the theme I'm using? Or is there a reason Soundcloud seems to randomly be the default (even though I haven't installed the Soundcloud Is Gold plugin)?